# how to count distinct on some columns

Tags: sql

Would like to add a count column in the SQL result to count if same email read on the same day for a same reportID count as 1.

DB #Report:

```
Reportid Name Country Doc      ReadDate        Email
100      AA   HK      011abc   2017-12-01   a@mail.com
100      BB   HK      011abc   2017-12-01   a@mail.com
200      BB   HK      012abc   2017-12-20   b@mail.com
200      BB   HK      012abc   2017-12-21   b@mail.com
300      CC   HK      013abc   2017-12-22   c@mail.com
300      CC   HK      013abc   2017-12-22   c@mail.com
300      CC   HK      013abc   2017-12-22   c@mail.com

Expected outcome:
    Reportid Name Country Doc      Date        Count
    100      AA   HK      012abc   2017-12-01  1
    200      BB   HK      012abc   2017-12-20  2
    300      CC   HK      012abc   2017-12-22  1
```

my SQL as below but failed to calculate the expected result to do the counting.
It generate all rows in the DB and everyrow count =1.

```
Select ReportId,Name,Country, Doc, Date, count(distinct concat(ReportId,Date,email))
from #Report
Group by Reportid,Name,Country, Doc, Date, email
```

Comment: What DB are you using? And if its SQL Server, what version?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this. Just remove `Date` column from group by.

```
Select ReportId,Name,Country, Doc, MIN(Date) Date, count(distinct concat(ReportId,Date,email))
from #Report
Group by Reportid,Name,Country, Doc, email
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one, Group only on ReportId, email and add readdate is not null condition. it will give you count of distinct ReportId, email, readdate and will take all other field's min value.

Considering that ReportId and email are not null fields.

```
Select ReportId, email, MIN(readdate), MIN(name), MIN(country), MIN(Doc), count(*) as Count
from Report
where readdate is not null 
Group by ReportId, email
```